# Html radio with same name in different div

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

Radio buttons are grouped together by name. However, is it not possible to have individual radio buttons with same name, but categorised into different divisions?

```
 <div id='image1'>
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> JPEG
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> BMP
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> PNG
 </div>
 <div id='image2'>
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> JPEG
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> BMP
   <input type="radio" name="type"/> PNG
 </div>
```

Theoretically it's an incorrent approach. Just needed some double confirmation.

I have a radio change event listenning to it,

```
 $('input:radio[name="type"]').change(function(){
      // do something
 });
```

How can I fix it accordingly ?

Comment: You cant. In the above HTML, all the values are belongs to single group.

Comment: No you can not. you can use same classname to element instead of giving same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have mentioned you cannot do that.
If you have control over the HTML you can append a unique identifier to the `name` attribute like this:

HTML:

```
<div id='image1'>
    <input type="radio" name="image1type" />JPEG
    <input type="radio" name="image1type" />BMP
    <input type="radio" name="image1type" />PNG</div>
<div id='image2'>
    <input type="radio" name="image2type" />JPEG
    <input type="radio" name="image2type" />BMP
    <input type="radio" name="image2type" />PNG</div>
```

and then modify your javascript like this:

```
$('input:radio[name$="type"]').change(function () {
    // do something
    console.log('change for ' + $(this).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/rCbaL/